# MongoDB and Big Data

Tags: python, mongodb, optimization, bigdata

I have a big database with one collection counting nearly 500 million documents, which looks as follow:

```
{'WP43234' : '12312312'}
```

First one is an accession, second is ID - basically it's a collection of links between two datasets. The problem is that many accessions point to the same ID, which makes it huge. I have an index on the first field, which speeds up lookup procedure, but it's still too slow (about 2 min per record):

```
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "TaxIDMapper.links"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "ProteinID" : 1
        },
        "name" : "ProteinID_1",
        "ns" : "TaxIDMapper.links"
    }
]
```

Main aim is to speed up following procedure in my app (written in python):

1. User uploads file with accessions (protein ID) (say up to 100k)
2. Look up accession and associated ID (most time consuming part)
3. Get data from second collection (small, works fast, no need to do anything with it)

Personally I think these should work:

- Database on SSD instead of HDD
- More powerful CPU
- Multiprocessing - requesting data in parallel (maybe threads are better?)

However I am not sure the speed up will be significant enough to process huge user requests. Is there anything else one could do? I was thinking about switching to SQL but it seems that MongoDB performs better.

Comment: I tried all of these but with not much success. Please let me know if there are any more options to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different structure for your collection : group the accession by taxonId like this:

```
{ 
  _id: taxonID, 
  acc: [ "WP43234", 
         "WP43234.1",
         "WP43234.2"
       ]
}
```

then create an index on `acc` field. 
Before thinking of upgrading hardware, make sur that your queries are optimized. Look at the `explain()` and make sure that index are correctly used (`IXSCAN` and not `COLLSCAN`). 
Use mongodb 3.4, **wiredTiger** engine with snappy compression

Comment: I will try it out and report back results. Thanks! Just one note: I am not using versions but accessions. Dataset is big since I have acc from different databases mapping to NCBI tax id.